# Can I show only pay through card option while check out?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

While I redirect user to payment, Currently, paypal gateway shows 2 options. 1) Pay through paypal 2) pay through card.

[image: This is the screen what I get when I redirect user to paypal]

But I dont wan't this. I don't want my user to have trouble of choosing the option.
So What I want is, my user should directly be redirected to below page. Currently it opens when we choose 2nd option in above image.

[image: My User Should See this directly. If possible, Not Even **create paypal account** option showed in last.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have only the "Pay with card option" ( can't remove Pay with PayPal option ) at PayPal checkout page. This is an intended behavior with PayPal Express Checkout integration. You can land the buyer at Pay with card option directly instead of landing at Pay with PayPal option then choose Pay with card.

In order to do that you will need to pass the NVP variable LANDINGPAGE=billing in the set express checkout API request, then PayPal will land the buyer at Pay with card option directly.

[Click here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) for more information about PayPal set express checkout API operation. You can search for LANDINGPAGE NVP variable in that link.

Comment: I checked this answer later on but this is the exact thing what I came to find out. Thanks :)